# where can I download this code

Tags: d3.js, interactive

I find a interesting website:http://www.brightpointinc.com/interactive/political_influence/
[image]
I want to learn its visualization using d3.
But when I download it, using `right click button`-------- `save as` The download page seems does not work. It seems lack some data, so I get back to the website to download some data, but it lacks some of them, can anyone send me an work version? thanks

Comment: Have a look at the source code, it will tell you what other files are loaded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [Lars says](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27044326/where-can-i-download-this-code#comment42610034_27044326), your best bet is to look at the source code. To do this, you can use something like [Chrome Developer Tools](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools) or [Firebug for Firefox](http://getfirebug.com/). I use the latter, so I'll take that as an example.

First, I'd right-click on the visualization itself, and click on `Inspect Element with Firebug`. This will pull up the HTML, which is only semi-helpful, since it only shows the *output* rather than the JavaScript code which created it.

To get at the JavaScript, you can use Firebug's `Script` tab. Most websites have more than one script, so you can hunt through the scripts being used by browsing through the dropdown menu in the second toolbar. The `_buildChords.js` script looks the most promising; that has some recognizable `d3` code in it. You could check out the others to see what else they're calling (since it looks like there might be others - `data.js`, `events.js`, and so on).

Happy learning.

[image]

Comment: thanks, I followed @Lars and get that code and data file